# M1 Mac KMM project build failure

Tags: android, ios, xcode, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm pretty new to KMM and I have hit a wall with making the project working in Xcode (gradle is failing). The Android app builds and runs without any issues.

The Xcode show failure with following text:

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Here's what I get in console:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:generic:storage:compileKotlinIosSimulatorArm64'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared:generic:storage:iosSimulatorArm64CompileKlibraries'.
   > Could not resolve com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3.
     Required by:
         project :shared:generic:storage
      > No matching variant of com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 was found. The consumer was configured to find a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a library, preferably optimized for non-jvm, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64' but:
          - Variant 'androidNativeArm32ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'android_arm32' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'androidNativeArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'android_arm64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'androidNativeX64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'android_x64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'androidNativeX86ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'android_x86' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'debugApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares an API of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'iosArm32ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_arm32' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_arm64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'iosX64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_x64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'jsIrApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'jsIrRuntimeElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'jsLegacyApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'jsLegacyRuntimeElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'jvmApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares an API of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'jvmRuntimeElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'linuxArm32HfpApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'linux_arm32_hfp' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'linuxArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'linux_arm64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'linuxMips32ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'linux_mips32' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'linuxMipsel32ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'linux_mipsel32' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'linuxX64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'linux_x64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'macosX64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'mingwX64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'mingw_x64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'mingwX86ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'mingw_x86' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares an API of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'tvosArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'tvos_arm64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'

========> I HAD TO REMOVE SOME LOGS TO FIT INTO 30,000 LINES LIMIT OF STACK OVERFLOW

          - Variant 'macosX64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'macos_x64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'mingwX64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'mingw_x64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares an API of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target (required 'ios_simulator_arm64')
          - Variant 'tvosArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'tvos_arm64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'tvosX64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'tvos_x64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'watchosArm32ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'watchos_arm32' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'watchosArm64ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'watchos_arm64' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
          - Variant 'watchosX86ApiElements-published' capability com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-coroutines-native-mt:0.7.3 declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'watchos_x86' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.target' with value 'ios_simulator_arm64'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm
```

I'm using MacBook Pro with M1 chip, `Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1` and following Java version:

```
$ java -version 
openjdk version "11.0.16.1" 2022-07-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.58+23-CA (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.58+23-CA (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem. In my case, the problem is that `com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings:0.7.3` doesn't support ARM simulator. I bumped the version to `0.9`, but that caused app to crash during runtime when calling certain methods in the library.

Alternative solution that works fine (but isn't ideal) is to **open the Xcode in Rosetta mode** which fires up simulator also using Rosetta.